# Are questions about regular travel within a home city on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I live in London, and wanted to ask a specific detailed question about using my [Oyster card](https://www.tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/oyster) (payment card for public transport in London). Does that count as travel, or because I'm a regular "commuter" in my home city, does that not count? (I don't have a regular journey, but I do often go to the same places). I'm in two minds, because to my mind, "travel" is something normally used to refer to somewhere away from your normal daily movements. I wondered what the community consensus is, though?

Comment: I think it's fine because knowledgable travellers would want to know as many road warrior tips as possible about the Oyster Card.  Just because something has overlap to local interest should not be grounds for exclusion.   So of course it's on topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you word the question to be unequivocally identifiable as a local commuter question, it may not be strictly off-topic, but would be sure to gather down-votes. Depending on the perceived topicality, it may also gather votes to close.

If you word the question to be more generic, essentially *making* it on-topic to general visitors to your city, then by all means, it would be on topic *and* might even gather you some up-votes as well.

Travel is travel, but... remember that [travel.se](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) is for (relatively) short term visitors/tourists, and [expatriates.se](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) is for long term visitors (work visas, etc).

Finally, you can always visit our [travel chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) and ask some of the regulars to help you word your question in as successful a way as possible, or they may even be able to help you with an answer (although an on-topic question asked would be preferable.)